# Can I improve this code using advance ruby concepts and I also wanted to print the list with item values?

Tags: ruby

Write a simple DSL for creating a shopping list. We should be able to specify the item name and quantity..
Something like.

My code works for pre-defined hash map, but once I take user input for creating a hash map it fails and also I want to improve my code by using more advanced concepts to achieve this result. Any suggestions ?

```
class Store
    def initialize(item, quantity)
       @products = { "item" => quantity }
       @cart = []
    end

    def add_to_cart( item )
        @cart << item
    end

    def add_product( item, price )
        @products[item] = price
    end

    def cart_total
        @cart.inject(0){|sum, item| sum + @products[item]}
    end

    def items
        @products.join(', ')
    end
end

puts "Please provide item name"
item = gets.chomp
puts "Please provide quantity associated with item"
quantity = gets.chomp.to_i
store = Store.new(item, quantity)
store.add_to_cart(item)

puts store.cart       
printf "$%6.2f", store.cart_total
```

Expected Result:

s1.list  #Should print complete list of the item and values added

sl.total # Should list the total price value for shopping done.

Comment: Not sure what whoever gave you this task meant by "DSL", but I'd argue there's none of that here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a quite broad question and it shouldn't, but I'd like to give my view on this anyway.

- Initialize empty Hash with default values ([Hash#new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-c-new))
- Don't forget `attr_reader` for accessing instance variable ([Module#attr_reader](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader))
- Check the docs for the method used here ([Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html), [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html), [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html))

Here is a possible refactor:

```
class Store

    attr_reader :cart, :products # you need to access the variables

    def initialize
        @cart = Hash.new(0) # initilize the Hash with default value
        @products = Hash.new
    end

    def add_to_cart(item, quantity)
        # increase by quantity, thanks to default value of the Hash,
        # only if the product is available
        if products.has_key? item # products thanks to the attr_reader, then see Hash docs
            cart[item] += quantity
            true
        else
            false
        end
    end

    def add_product(item, price)
        products[item] = price
    end

    def cart_total
        cart.sum { |k, v| products[k] * v }
    end

    def products_list
        products.keys
    end
end
```

So, you can use this class as follows:

```
store = Store.new
store.add_product("Apple", 10.0 )
store.add_product("Lemon", 12.0 )
store.add_product("Melon", 20.0 )

store.products_list
#=> ["Apple", "Lemon", "Melon"]
store.products
#=> {"Apple"=>10.0, "Lemon"=>12.0, "Melon"=>20.0}

store.add_to_cart('Apple', 4) #=> true
store.add_to_cart('Melon', 5) #=> true
store.add_to_cart('Carrot', 1)  #=> false # not available, not added

store.cart # thanks to attr_reader
#=> {"Apple"=>4, "Melon"=>2}

store.cart_total
#=> 140.0
```

You could think also to define a `Cart` class...

Comment: And I have a few other suggestions too, but it's not you who asked for improvements :)

Comment: Yes @SergioTulentsev I left the `store` reader there for OP, just in case.. :) Suggestions always welcome :))

Comment: Well, here you go: 1) Enumerable#sum accepts a block. 2) that available_products check is veeeery inefficient (creates a temp array each time. Why not use the hash directly?) and yes, 3) use your readers :)

Comment: BTW, check out [exercism](https://exercism.io/), if you haven't already.

Comment: Grrr, I cannot get what you mean :)

Comment: Oh? See definition of `cart_total`, for example. See using the readers there? I too do not :)

Comment: Oh I get it. But I considered instance variable or reader the same. Using instance vars allows to just delete a symbol from the code, in case deciding of not using readers later. But I feel I'm missing something. Is your suggestion for a good practice or something different? (I'm cleaning up my comments).

Comment: " in case deciding of not using readers later" - this hadn't happen to me even once. You either remove the whole thing or you don't. Using readers everywhere, even privately, allows for more stable code. Say, you wanted to add a lazy initialization to your `store` accessor. If you were using methods everywhere, you simply replace `attr_reader` with a full method which does memoization or what-have-you. And the rest of the code stays exactly the same. Now imagine the code that uses instance variables.

Comment: @iGian Thanks alot for such quick turnaround. Your solution is really very helpful.